# How to deal with redirects to a bookmark within a page in Scrapy (911 error)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am very new to programming, so apologies if this is a rookie issue. I am a researcher, and I've been building spiders to allow me to crawl specific search results of IGN, the gaming forum. The first spider collects each entry in the search results, along with URLs, and then the second spider crawls each of those URLs for the content.

The problem is that IGN redirects URLs associated with a specific post to a new URL that incorporates a #bookmark at the end of the address. This allows the visitor to the page to jump directly down to the post in question, but I want my spider to crawl over the entire thread. In addition, my spider ends up with a (911) error after the redirect and returns no data. The only data retrieved is from any search results that linked directly to a thread rather than a post.

I am absolutely stumped and confused, so any help would amazing! Both spiders are attached below.

Spider 1:

```
myURLs = [] baselineURL = "https://www.ign.com/boards/search/186716896/?q=broforce&o=date&page=" for counter in range (1,5):
    myURLs.append(baselineURL + str(counter))

class BroforceIGNScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foundation"
    start_urls = myURLs

    def parse(self,response):
        for post in response.css("div.main"):
            yield {
                'title': post.css("h3.title a::text").extract_first(),
                'author': post.css("div.meta a.username::text").extract_first(),
                'URL': post.css('h3 a').xpath('@href').extract_first(),
            }
```

Spider 2:

```
URLlist = []
baseURL = "https://www.ign.com/boards/"

import csv
with open('BroforceIGNbase.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        URLlist.append(baseURL + row['URL'])

class BroforceIGNScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "posts2"
    start_urls = URLlist

    # handle_httpstatus_list = [301]

    def parse(self,response):
        for post in response.css(".messageList"):
            yield {
                'URL': response.url,
                'content': post.css(".messageContent article").extract_first(),
                'commentauthor': post.css("div.messageMeta a::text").extract_first(),
                'commentDateTime': post.css('div.messageMeta a span.DateTime').xpath('@title').extract_first(),
            }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce any of the issues you describe, not the redirect nor the 911 error.  Can you share a particular url where the problems occur? Also, the url segment (the #part) should be ignored when making the request, so that is unlikely to play any part in this.

Comment: I just reran the spider and for some reason it is working now without me having made any change to the code. Sorry for sending you on a rabbit trail. But it's only pulling the first post on a page - might you know why that's the case? It should run through everything on the page.